# Does MobileNet SSD v2 only capture aleatoric uncertainty (and so not the epistemic one)?

Tags: bayesian-deep-learning, uncertainty-quantification, single-shot-multibox-detector, epistemic-uncertainty

Regarding the MobileNet SSD v2 model, I was wondering to what extend it captures uncertainty of the predictions.

There are 2 types of uncertainty, data uncertainty (aleatoric) and model uncertainty (epistemic).

The model outputs bounding boxes with a confidence score, but what uncertainty does that score represent?

From what I know models usually only capture aleatoric uncertainty in their predictions, but not the epistemic one. Is this also true for MobileNet SSD v2?